# Facebook Page Likes and its information getting API returned empty data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, typo3

I have seen similar posts on this site, but none has solved my problem, the api version has changed and some endpoints are deprecated.

When I use, even the Graph API Explorer I get a response with empty data.

```
// Instantiating the Facebook class
$this->api = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => $ apiId,
    'app_secret' => $ apiSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.11',
    ]);
....
// Creating the authentication link
$helper = $this->api->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['manage_pages', 'publish_pages', 'read_insights']; // Optional permissions
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl ('http://dev2.example.co/smms/index.php?id=16', $permissions);
...
// Getting the total of likes of the page (the endpoint 'fan_count' does not work for this version)
$this->api->get('/'.$this->id_profile.' / likes', $this->getAccessTokenAttribute())
```

The result is empty and the access token is correct in all cases.

On the other hand, when I make the call to only the information on the page, it only delivers the data of the name of the page and the id

```
protected 'decodedBody' =>
    array (size = 2)
      'name' => string 'Test Page' (length = 9)
      'id' => string '1989831694572991' (length = 16)
```

I would appreciate if you could guide me to get all the information on the page as the likes. I do not know if any page level permission is missing in order to achieve it.

I am working with TYPO3 7.6 and PHP 5.6.

Comment: No, `/likes` is not the number of page fans, it is the list of other pages liked by your page. `fan_count` _is_ the correct field, and it works fine in API v2.11, as https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1989831694572991%3Ffields%3Dfan_count&version=v2.11 easily proves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change likes to fan_count

```
$this->api->get('/'.$this->id_profile.'?fields=fan_count', $this->getAccessTokenAttribute());
```

I think `fans_count` is working in v2.11. If its not working for you then kindly share some more code for inspection

[image]

Comment: With  `$this->api->get('/'.$this->id_profile.' / fan_count', $this->getAccessTokenAttribute())`  I get this error `Unknown path components: /fan_count exception code:2500 file:/typo3conf/ext/smms/Resources/Private/Libs/facebook/src/Facebook/Exceptions/FacebookResponseException.php line:131` but using as you show in the screenshot `$this->api->get('/'.$this->id_profile.'?fields=fan_count', $this->getAccessTokenAttribute());` works. Thank you!